# Direction of grain when making stiles and rails for a door

Tags: rip-cut, door

Some years ago I saw an article about how to rip wood and put the pieces together again so the twisting was reduced (part A twisted opposite part B so the result still was straight).

I have since then looked for said article to no avail.

Does anyone have a good explanation for tricks and rules for this?

Comment: Are we talking about a normal door in a house or like something in cabinetry?

Comment: @Matt Anything. I tried (and failed?) to ask the question in a general way for tips&tricks while still adhering to stackexchange's rule about being Q&A and not a discussion forum. bowlturner below answered quite right with a "flip the board both ways - there is nothing magic about it".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally how I do it is after ripping the wood, line them all back up.  then flip every other board over the long way.  If the board wants to cup, flipping every other board reduces how much it can cup, because each one will want to 'bend' in the opposite direction.

By flipping them the long way it also helps with bows and twisting.

[image]